# How to check whether local time is behind server time (MySQL)

Tags: php, date

I am creating a online booking mechanism and I want to validate the date entered in from the client by checking whether the day entered is not a day before than the current server day or not. Is there any method to do that?

Comment: Get sever time to JavaScript and compare with the users local time however you probably want the code written for you so you'd have to hire a developer.

Comment: or if you want to do that server side convert to timestamp `strtotime()`

Comment: @shaN what they are asking for requires JavaScript, you can't get the users local time using PHP.

Comment: This would be part of your normal form submission validation. Since you ask this question I have to assume you haven't done any validation? I can't tell, there's no code whatsoever.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes I was asking for a method and i dont have any code, yet.

Comment: This question isn't really answerable. You've provided no code, we can't see what format the date is in. Also, you seem to have done zero research. [Use Google](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+compare+two+dates&t=h_&ia=qa). Try something. If it doesn't work: Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
$yesterday = strtotime("-1 days");
$enteredDate = strtotime("2017-08-27");   // the date the client entered
if( $enteredDate < $yesterday )
    echo "Bad Date!\n";
else
    echo "Good Date!\n";
```

This compares the entered date with yesterday's date.